# Google chrome`s inspect is not working properly with css overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

[image]Now I am trying to make navigation but when I check its responsiveness in chrome`s inpect it doesn`t work properly. Is it chrome`s bug?
[my code](https://codepen.io/Dilmurod99/pen/XvrmyV)

Any Help Please?

Comment: No problem it seems. what are you trying to inspect? Can you provide screenshots

Comment: you can see now

Comment: In future, it would be better to explain what do you mean with "doesn't work properly". Does it show wrong CSS styles or cause some rendering errors? More often than not the real problem is misunderstanding how DevTools are supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete this

```
.nav-links li {
opacity: 0;
}
```

It is on `@media screen and (max-width:768px)`

Comment: Otherwise, you could set **opacity: 1.0**

Comment: I don't understand because your code is working perfect on my screen, mozilla and chrome. Opacity changement was because we don't see links in responsive navbar.

Comment: it is working but in chrome`s inspect section it shows differntly as above picture

Comment: it's weird, because i have test too with the inspector and it works, maybe update chrome ?

Comment: Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) i think it is the latest one